# Find the nth largest values in the top row and omit the rest of the columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, data-cleaning

I am trying to change a data frame such that I only include those columns where the first value of the row is the nth largest.

For example, here let's assume I want to only include the columns where the top value in row 1 is the 2nd largest (top 2 largest).

```
dat1 = data.frame(a = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5), b = c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10), c = c(0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16), d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5))

    a   b    c  d
1 0.1 0.6 0.12 NA
2 0.2 0.7 0.13 NA
3 0.3 0.8 0.14 NA
4 0.4 0.9 0.15 NA
5 0.5 0.1 0.16 0.5
```

such that `a` and `d` are removed, because `0.1` and `NA` are not the 2nd largest values in 
row 1. Here `0.6` and `0.12` are larger than `0.1` and `NA` in column `a` and `d` respectively.

```
    b    c 
1 0.6 0.12 
2 0.7 0.13
3 0.8 0.14 
4 0.9 0.15 
5 0.1 0.16
```

Is there a simple way to subset this? I do not want to order it, because that will create problems with other data frames I have that are related.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to *"only include the columns where the top value in the columns/values in row 1 is the 2nd largest"* How can you have multiple columns? Shouldn't there only be *one* column whose first value is the 2nd largest across the first row?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have multiple columns in the way I have a, b, c, d vectors in the data frame. I have edited the post now. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing pieca's answer, you can encapsulate that into a function.
Also, this way, the returning data.frame won't be sorted.

```
get_nth <- function(df, n) {
  df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric) # edit
  cols <- names(sort(df[1, ], na.last = NA, decreasing = TRUE))
  cols <- cols[seq(n)]
  df <- df[names(df) %in% cols]
  return(df)
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the first row of your `data.frame`, and then subset by names:

```
cols <- names(sort(dat1[1,], na.last = NA, decreasing = TRUE))
> dat1[,cols[1:2]]
    b    c
1 0.6 0.12
2 0.7 0.13
3 0.8 0.14
4 0.9 0.15
5 0.1 0.16
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without sorting it?

Comment: this solution copies the 1st row and sorts only it, `dat1` is not affected

Comment: When I try to apply your suggestion for my real data set it doesn't get the nth largest values. It skips some columns.

Comment: Note that my data frame is not ordered alphabetically. I just tried for another data set with similar structure where the columns were not ordered alphabetically, and I did not get the nth largest values.

Comment: @Mataunited17 what do you mean by 'skips'? Is the order of columns in `cols` as you expect? Are all of your columns `numeric`? (run `str(yourdata)` ) Whether your column names are in alphabetical order doesn't matter here

Comment: The order of the columns do not come out as expected. Some of the values that should be there were not there. Apparently, it is not numeric according to `is.numeric`, but it is numeric according to `str()`.

Comment: If for some reason some are not numeric, they aren't gonna be sorted the same way the others are. It's really strange that `is.numeric()` isn't returning `TRUE` for the variables considered numeric by `str()`, but you could maybe force all columns to numeric with `as.numeric()`, if they have the right format. I'll update my answer with that alternative.

Comment: Remember that if you index a data.frame with `[n]`, it'll return a data.frame. If you do `is.numeric(df[n])`, it'll return `FALSE` even though it's a numeric column, because it'll be a data.frame instead. If you want to check an individual column, use `[[n]]` indexing instead, and it'll return a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an inverted rank of the first row and take the top nth columns:

```
> r <- rank(-dat1[1,], na.last=T)
> r <- r <= 2
> dat1[,r]
    b    c
1 0.6 0.12
2 0.7 0.13
3 0.8 0.14
4 0.9 0.15
5 0.1 0.16
```